# Reading files from an SD card using iOS14

Tags: ios, swift, sd-card

I'm trying to read files from an SD card. The following code works great when my iOS app is run in Xcode's Simulator, but fails to read the directory when i build to the iPad.  A similar question was asked 10 years ago and it appears no solution existed back then.

```swift
func getFilesfromUSB() {
        let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Volumes/" + sdCardName + "/FILES")
        var fileURLs: [URL] = []
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated ).async {
            do {
                fileURLs = try self.fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: filePath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
                print("getting files via USB")
                print(fileURLs)
            } catch {
                print("failed to read directory – bad permissions, perhaps?")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parseFiles(from: fileURLs)
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I go about reading (and writing) to an SD card from iOS 14+?

Comment: You can't read directly from a location outside your apps Sandbox. You can use [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) to ask the user to select a file and make it available to your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. Sad that my app is allowed to import files from the internet but not from an attached SD card. Is there really no workaround? Can't I ask the user for permission?

Comment: Or if the card is inserted into a mac, can I run a script to copy/sync the files to the user's iCloud drive and access them live from there instead?

Comment: You can do it from the command line, the path to the iCloud Drive is `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/`

Comment: Even if the files are on the iCloud Drive your app would still need to ask permission, via the document picker controller to access the files. Your app can expose *its* documents folder to the iCloud Drive and then the user can copy the files into that folder, either cia their Mac, the iCloud web site or the files app on their iOS device. Accessing the Internet and accessing files on the device are very different things from a privacy and security perspective. I can buy a newspaper at the newsagent but I can't look through your home filing cabinet.